# Access back office Prestashop

Tags: http-status-code-404, prestashop, devtools, enter, backoffice

I have a problem in the Prestashop back office.
When I try to log in with my credentials, the page reloads every time, but it doesn't log in and the login screen appears.
In the console I get GET 404 and "Failed to load source map in DevTools: Failed to load content for chrome-extension: //gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net :: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND."

Comment: Try with a different browser. If problem persists, enable debug mode in your PrestaShop. You can do it editing `config/defines.inc.php` and changing `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to true. This way, it will show errors and you can debug.

Comment: Also make sure your shop had not been hacked => https://build.prestashop-project.org/news/major-security-vulnerability-on-prestashop-websites/

modified files can cause backoffice login not working anymore